# What is better many small interfaces or less big interfaces in RESTful API?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I want to create better RESTful APIs for mobile application. A simple example:

```
user model:
 - firstname
 - lastname
 - gender

services:
GET /users          => list of all users
POST /users         => create a new user
PUT /users          => update a bulk of users
GET /users/{id}     => one special users
PUT /users/{id}     => update a special user
```

It is better to create small interfaces like this instead of `PUT /users/{id}` ?:

```
PUT /usersFirstname/{id}
PUT /usersLastname/{id}
PUT /usersGender/{id}
```

On the one hand a mobile application only send the changed value and not the hole user model. But on the other hand I have many methods with nearly the same business logic and more maintenance.

Is there an best practice approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### REST resources

The key concept of REST is a *resource*. And that's how Roy T. Fielding defined a *resource* in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of his PhD dissertation (highlights are not present in the dissertation):

> [**5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers**](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)
>
> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. **Any information that can be named can be a resource**: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.
>
> [...]
>
> **REST uses a resource identifier to identify the particular resource involved in an interaction between components.** [...]

A resource must have *at least one URI* to identify it. The URI is the *name* and *address* of a resource. Conceptually, you have a *user* resource hence you need a URI for it. So the following approach is a must go:

```
GET /users          # list of all users
POST /users         # create a new user
PUT /users          # update a bulk of users
GET /users/{id}     # one special users
PUT /users/{id}     # update a special user
```

And the following makes no sense when you have a *user* resource:

```
PUT /usersFirstname/{id}
PUT /usersLastname/{id}
PUT /usersGender/{id}
```

### Performing partial updates

To deal with partial updates, use the `PATCH` HTTP verb. The `PUT` HTTP verb should be used to replace the entire resource with a new representation.

For partial updates, some approaches consider the fields of a main resource as sub resources. Then `PUT` can be used to replace the sub-resource with a new representation. Something like:

```
PUT /users/{id}/firstname
PUT /users/{id}/lastname
PUT /users/{id}/gender
```

I'm not saying that's a *good* or *bad* approach. That's just *another* approach to perform partial updates.

### Retrieving partial representations

To retrieve a partial representation of a resource, use [content negotiation or a query string parameter to filter the fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38245469/1426227).

Answer (score 1):

Usually a web interface should be chunky not chatty thus you should probably post the whole user at once. This is also mentioned in the [Microsoft API implementation guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-api-implementation/)

Comment: Then I have to allow null values? In case the UI wants to change the gender but don't know the name at this point.

Comment: You should send the complete user at once, containing all of its data if possible. You do want to make as few request as possible to reduce server resources.